# Optional parameters with generated ID

Tags: typescript

Say I have an interface User

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  balance: number;
}
```

This is how the object is saved in my database. When creating a new user, I want to type my created object

```
const newUser = {
  email: 'test@test.com';
  username: 'test';
  balance: 12345;
} as User
```

Notice that the `id` field is missing here, because it is auto-generated by the database.

However, if I were to make `id` an optional field, I can run into `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

What's the best approach for this? First thought would be to have a `PreDBUser` and a `User` that extends is, but that seems dirty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) to remove properties from type:

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  balance: number;
}

export type UserWithoutId = Omit<User, 'id'>
```

Comment: there is no typescheck, so you can do "Omit<User, 'noexist'>", also you need import User type.

Answer (score 1):

on the constructor you can use optional variable with `?` (optionals)

```
export class User {
  constructor(public id?: string,
              public email: string,
              public username: string,
              public balance: number){
 }
}
```

then this usage will not throw error

```
const newUser = {
  email: 'test@test.com';
  username: 'test';
  balance: 12345;
} as User
```

Answer (score 0):

I use helper types for this, that connected to main type like this:

```
export type User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
  balance: number;
}

export type UserFields = keyof User
export type UserFieldsExtract<F extends UserFields> = Extract<UserFields, F>
export type UserPropsPick<P extends UserFields> = Pick<User, P>

// User type without id prop
const userWithoutId: UserPropsPick<'email' | 'username' | 'balance'> = {...}
```

Comment: There is a builtin `Pick` type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk

Comment: @UjinT34 and what?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that you use it